# How to achieve transmission only at normal incidence?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, material-science, reflection

Is there any material that only transmits normally incident radiation and reflects it when it's incident at any other angle? Or any way to achieve such an effect?

For example, a mirror that if you shine a laser pointer at, only lets the beam through it when it hits the surface at a right angle.

Comment: You can achieve that with a phase hologram, if you like.  I haven't seen any reflective implementations, but there are plenty of applications for the absorptive type, simple window shutters are an example and so are monitor filters that don't let people looking at the screen from the side see what's on it.

Comment: @CuriousOne, I thought about the monitor filter type material, but I do need it to be reflective and I'm not sure if covering it with reflective coating would still allow light to pass at normal incidence.

Comment: I don't know about a simple solution that avoids having to use some sort of interference filter or, more generally, a synthetic phase hologram. I am sure the optics or meta-materials folks have worked this case out somewhere, but you will have to do a literature search to find it.